# Не мудрый SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Суть вот в чем.
Есть запись в таблице с целочисленным полем "field" и нужно вытащить другую записть, у которой значение этого поля больше чем у текущей записи, но меньше, чем у всех остальных записей в этой таблице. Туплю я чего-то=\

Comment: Вытащить нужно такие записи для каждой записи таблицы или только одну? Если одну, то у исходной по крайней мере должен быть известен id или значение поля "field". Поле "field" уникально, или возможны повторения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разве это не вторая запись при сортировке по возрастанию....??

Comment: Согласен она самая

Comment: Говорил же туплю=) Сегодня в 00:00 спать ложусь)) Спасибо всем за ответы. Всем плюсики, кроме тех, кто пытался решить задачу с помощью вложенных запросов. Ребят, без обид, но это извращенство какое то=\

Comment: При таком раскладе ближе всего оказался Modus, так что лавры ему...

Comment: @aachurin, не согласен... По условию - "чем у всех остальных записей в этой таблице", а не "чем у остальных больших", так-что его запрос вообще не верный!

Comment: Перечитал внимательнее вопрос, действительно, ты прав.
Но это будет иметь смысл, только если значение field __текущей записи__ заведомо меньше значений field других записей в таблице.

Answer (score 1):

value - значение с которым нужно сравнить

```
SELECT * FROM `table` A WHERE `field` > value AND `field` < ALL (SELECT `field` FROM `table` B WHERE A.field != B.field AND B.field != value)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE field > @value ORDER BY field ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      t.field,
      (
          SELECT MIN(_t.Field)
          FROM TableName _t
          WHERE
             _t.Field>t.Field
      )
FROM TableName t
```